# Join all files in a directory, with a separator

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory containing hundreds of files (each having several chars). I want to join them into a single file with a separator, "|".

I tried

```
find . -type f | (while read line; do; cat $line; echo "|"; done;) > output.txt
```

But that created an infinite loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can exclude `output.txt` from the output of `find` using `-not -name output.txt` (or as you already pointed out in the comments below, simply place the output file outside the target directory).

For example:

```
find . -type f -not -name output.txt -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "|" \; > output.txt
```

I've also taken the liberty to replace your `while/cat/echo` with a couple of `-exec` params so we can do the whole thing using a single `find` call.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointer. This worked for me `find . -type f | (while read line; do; cat $line; echo "|"; done;) > ../output.txt`

Comment: @Dogbert that would work :). BTW, you don't need the semicolon after `do` i.e. `(while read line; do cat $line; echo "|"; done;)`

Answer (score 2):

*To answer the title of the question, since it's the first in google results (the output.txt problem is actually unrelated):

This is what I use to join `.jar` files to run Java app with files in `lib/`:

EntityManagerStoreImpl

```
ondra@lenovo:~/work/TOOLS/JawaBot/core$ ls
catalog.xml  nbactions.xml  nb-configuration.xml  pom.xml  prepare.sh  resources  run.sh  sql  src  target  workdir

ondra@lenovo:~/work/TOOLS/JawaBot/core$ echo `ls -1` | sed 's/\W/:/g'
catalog:xml:nbactions:xml:nb:configuration:xml:pom:xml:prepare:sh:resources:run:sh:sql:src:target:workdir
```

The file listing may be of course replaced with `find ...` or anything.
The `echo` is there to replace newlines with spaces.

Final form:

```
java -cp $(echo `ls -1 *.jar` | sed 's/\W/:/g') com.foo.Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I reused Ondra's answer, but with absolute path instead.

Command :

```
echo $( \find '/home/user/[path-to-webapp]/WEB-INF/lib' -name '*.jar' -print0) |  \
sed 's#\.jar/#.jar:#g'
```

Note: I use `#` as `sed`'s separator to not match the last jar in the list.

Results:

> /home/user/[path-to-webapp]/WEB-INF/lib/jar1.jar:home/user/[path-to-webapp]/WEB-INF/lib/jar2.jar[...
>   and so
>   on...]:/home/user/[path-to-webapp]/WEB-INF/lib/last-jar.jar

Then, I can use this output in a `javac -classpath` command.